# SQL COUNT NULL values

Tags: sql, t-sql, count, null

I am trying to find the Playlist(s) with 10 or more tracks that have NULL values in the Composer column.

Here are the tables

```
CREATE TABLE [Playlist]
(
[PlaylistId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[Name] NVARCHAR(120),
CONSTRAINT [PK_Playlist] PRIMARY KEY  ([PlaylistId])
);

CREATE TABLE [PlaylistTrack]
(
[PlaylistId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[TrackId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_PlaylistTrack] PRIMARY KEY  ([PlaylistId], [TrackId]),
FOREIGN KEY ([PlaylistId]) REFERENCES [Playlist] ([PlaylistId]) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
FOREIGN KEY ([TrackId]) REFERENCES [Track] ([TrackId]) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE [Track]
(
[TrackId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[Name] NVARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL,
[AlbumId] INTEGER,
[MediaTypeId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[GenreId] INTEGER,
[Composer] NVARCHAR(220),
[Milliseconds] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[Bytes] INTEGER,
[UnitPrice] NUMERIC(10,2)  NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Track] PRIMARY KEY  ([TrackId]),
FOREIGN KEY ([AlbumId]) REFERENCES [Album] ([AlbumId]) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
FOREIGN KEY ([GenreId]) REFERENCES [Genre] ([GenreId]) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
FOREIGN KEY ([MediaTypeId]) REFERENCES [MediaType] ([MediaTypeId]) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

Here is what I have so far. I think the query logic is good but is this the correct way to count up null values?

```
SELECT P.PlaylistId, P.name
FROM Playlist P
    JOIN PlaylistTrack pt ON p.PlaylistId = pt.PlaylistId
    JOIN Track t ON pt.TrackId = t.TrackId
GROUP BY p.PlaylistId
HAVING COUNT(t.Composer IS NULL) >=10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to compare `COUNT(T.Compser) >= 10` in the `SELECT` clause is a mistake. That's a comparison that is going to (always) return a true/false. That subquery also has no relation to your outer query. I'm actually surprised that it even runs without an error.

You should be able to use the `HAVING` clause, which is used to compare aggregates:

```
SELECT
    P.PlaylistID,
    P.Name
FROM
    Playlist P
INNER JOIN PlaylistTrack PT ON PT.PlaylistID = P.PlaylistID
INNER JOIN Track T ON
    T.TrackID = PT.TrackID AND
    T.Composer IS NULL
GROUP BY
    P.PlaylistID,
    P.Name
HAVING
    COUNT(*) >= 10
```

EDIT: You've changed your question. With the new query, the problem is that `COUNT()` will always count a row regardless of what the value is inside unless that value is `NULL`. `T.Composer IS NULL` will evaluate to a value - either true or false (1/0), which means that regardless of the value of `T.Composer`, every row will be counted towards the aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of NULL, can't you just state something like <> 0 ? or = 0 ?

or at least try:

Where T.Composer IS NULL or col = ''

or Where T.Composer IsNull(col, '') = ''

Answer (score 0):

I would use left join instead of inner. This way it will still return a row even if there are no rows within that query. Sometimes this has a chance to break your statement since it can't count null.